# Assembly.Load strange behavior

Tags: .net, assemblies, version, gac

I have "Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll" V2.0.3.0 in my GAC of two machines.

I am running this line in both of them:

```
Assembly.Load("Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
```

(note the version is 2.0.0.0 and not 2.0.3.0)

On one machine this fails (as I would expect). In another it works and the loaded dll is 2.0.3.0. Actually on this machine every version lower than 3 works (and loads 3).

How can you explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/13a95aa8-4dc3-4b91-af19-c460c6e1fca6?prof=required

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have `Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll` in your `bin` folder. Check the assembly [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx):

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("XXX");
Console.WriteLine(assembly.Location);
```

Comment: So what does the `Location` property equals to once the assembly loaded?

Comment: Regardless of the version (providing it is < 3) I as I get C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Web.Services2\2.0.3.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to loading a "Specific Version" flag. If you check the assembly properties in References folder in Visual Studio, it shows a "Specific Version" property which I think specifies whether to link to specific version of an assembly or not (default is false). By default, it will link to any specific OR newer version of the assembly and that whats happening here I guess.

So there might be some option in Load method itself that specifies whether to load the specific version ONLY or fall back to a more recent one if specific is not found.

Comment: The assembly is not referenced at all - I load it from GAC. This is what is strange...